# How to get the navigation bar to align to the center

Tags: html, css

The code for my navigation bar is from [over here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_float_advanced).

But, it aligns to the left and not to the center. How could I do this?

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-align:center;
   font-family:arial;
}

li {
   float: left;
}

   a:link, a:visited {
   display: block;
   width: 120px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   background-color:black;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 6px;
   font-family:arial;
   text-decoration: none;
} 

   a:hover, a:active {
   background-color:grey;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text-align` will not affect floated elements. However it will affect *inline* elements.

Change:

```css
li {
   float: left;
}
```

To:

```css
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kc51q6g4/).

---

> Thank you, but there are white gaps between the buttons, how can I close them ?

To fix the white gaps you'll need to give your ul a font-size of 0 and your li a font-size of whichever size font you want your list items to have.

```css
ul {
    font-size: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kc51q6g4/1/).

Comment: Thank you, but there are white gaps between the buttons, how can I close them ?

Comment: The "gap" is caused by the line breaks in the code and and code indents. You can either minify your code or you can use code comments from the end of the first line to the beginning of the second line.

Comment: @Ben to fix the white gaps you'll need to give your `ul` a `font-size` of `0` and your `li` a `font-size` of whichever size font you want your list items to have.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `margin: 0 auto` and `display: table` if you don't want to specify a width.

**Note:** w3schools is not the best resource; I would recommend [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/), and the official docs at [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/). When using Google to search for HTML / CSS resources use `search term -w3schools` to avoid w3schools results.

[Have an example!](http://jsbin.com/toviqa/1/edit)

CSS

```
ul {
   display: table;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

or you can also use:

CSS

```
ul {
    width: 500px; /* whatever width size */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This option would be good if you need to support IE 6/7.

It's worth noting that depending on what you want to achieve you should center the `<body>` itself or another element that wraps all the content that you want centered. In this very basic example I use `<div class="wrap">` to center my content.

[Another example!](http://jsbin.com/toviqa/2/edit)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="content">
    This is more content
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.content {
    padding: 20px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

}

li {
    float: left;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #98bf21;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #7A991A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, add **display:table** and **margin:auto** for **ul** class as below:

```
ul {
 display: table;
 margin: 0 auto;
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align:center;
 font-family:arial;
}
```

That's it, your navigation bar will be positioned to center.